# [ROS2] Odometry with Velocity feedback

Tags: ros, ros2, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Configuration:

- ROS 2 Distro: Humble
- OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04

Hi there, I have a 2 wheeled robot with differential drive kinematics and odometry setup, I implemented `EKF` and added an IMU.

The robot has an emergency button feature that cuts any velocity command sent to the motors (while `cmd_vel` is still publishing in the background). I am using a position and velocity `state_interface` and I made sure that the feedback is reaching the `diff drive` plugin.

The problem is that my odometry twist values are taken directly from the `cmd_vel` topic, so even though the robot isn't moving the odometry keeps going on.

How can I integrate my wheel velocity feedback with the `diff drive` plugin??

ros2_control tag:

```
<ros2_control name="${name}" type="system">
  <hardware>
      <plugin>amr_control/DiffDriveSystemHardware</plugin>
      <param name="wheel_radius">0.098</param>
      <param name="wheel_seperation">0.705</param>
  </hardware>
  <joint name="left_wheel_joint">
    <command_interface name="velocity">
      <param name="min">-1.5</param>
      <param name="max">1.5</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position"/>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="right_wheel_joint">
    <command_interface name="velocity">
      <param name="min">-1.5</param>
      <param name="max">1.5</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position"/>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
  </joint>
</ros2_control>
```

HW Interface read Implementation:

```
hardware_interface::return_type DiffDriveSystemHardware::read(const rclcpp::Time &time, const rclcpp::Duration &period)
   {
for (uint i = 0; i < hw_commands_.size(); i++)
{
  hw_positions_[i] = comms->getPosition(info_.joints[i].name.c_str());
  hw_velocities_[i] = comms->getVelocity(info_.joints[i].name.c_str());
}

return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
}
```

Example Scenario:

```
cmd_vel topic -> linear.x = 0.5
real_motor -> linear.x = 0.0 (because of the emergency stop)
HW interface joint state -> linear.x = 0.0 (reading from real hardware)
diff_drive/odom -> linear.x = 0.5 (same as cmd_vel)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417708/%5Bros2%5D-odometry-with-velocity-feedback/) by [Ammar Albakri](https://answers.ros.org/users/106635/ammar-albakri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2023-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it, it seems the open_loop parameter has to be false in order for the system to use the feedback.

---

Originally posted by [Ammar Albakri](https://answers.ros.org/users/106635/ammar-albakri/) with karma: 31 on 2023-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0